# jquery ajax multiple drop down list events

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, drop-down-menu

I have two drop downs that I want to use to get some results. If the user changes the first drop down it will change the selection options in the second. I can get the select options to be replaced but the event will not fire first time in the second dropdown but after that will fire incrementally.

I think it is because .html is creating a new dom each time it is run, but I have no idea how to stop this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("form[name='search_form']").change(function(event){
        if($(event.target).is("#searchregionid")){
            regionid = $("#searchregionid").val();
            searchData = "searchregionid="+regionid;
            searchFor(searchData);
            getCountrySelection(searchData);
        }
        else if($(event.target).is("select[name='searchcountryid']")){
             $("select[name='searchcountryid']").change(function(){
                $("select[name='searchcountryid'] option:selected").each(function(){
                    countryid = $("#searchcountryid").val();
                    searchData = "searchcountryid="+countryid;
                    searchFor(searchData);
                }); 
             });
        }
    });
});

function searchFor(searchData){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/s_city_index.php",
       data: searchData,
       success:function(msg){
           $(".indexList").ajaxComplete(function(event,request){
                if(msg.toString() != "searcherror")
                    $(".indexList").html(msg);
                else
                   $(".indexList").html('No matching results.');
           });
       }
   });
}

function getCountrySelection(searchData){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/s_coun_sel.php",
       data: searchData,
       success:function(msg){
           $("select[name='searchcountryid']").ajaxComplete(function(event,request){
                if(msg.toString() != "searcherror")
                    $("select[name='searchcountryid']").html(msg);                
                else
                   $("select[name='searchcountryid']").html('No matching results.');            
           });
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are defining ajaxComplete inside of a success callback. The ajaxComplete function is a GLOBAL callback, that gets run after every ajax call. Try something more like this:

```
function searchFor(searchData){
    $.post("/s_city_index.php", searchData, function(msg){
        if(msg.toString() != "searcherror"){
            $(".indexList").html(msg);
        } else {
            $(".indexList").html('No matching results.');
        }
    });
}

function getCountrySelection(searchData){
    $.post("/s_coun_sel.php", searchData, function(msg){
        if(msg.toString() != "searcherror"){
            $("select[name='searchcountryid']").html(msg);                
        } else {
            $("select[name='searchcountryid']").html('No matching results.');
        }
    });
}
```